# AutoIt script to mount/open an ISO file

Tags: autoit

I need an AutoIt script to mount/open an [ISO image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image) file without using any programs like [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip), etc. Generally we use 7-Zip to mount ISO image files, but without using any of those programs, I need an AutoIt script to open ISO image files.

Comment: So you deleted the original question. Well you shot yourself in the foot there, I had given you the answer in a comment.

Comment: [`FileInstall`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileInstall.htm) appears to be able to bundle binary files into the exe as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is no pure AutoIT user-defined function (UDF) which can extract an ISO image file. You could use a DLL file written in C for this, like libcdio. But writing a AutoIT wrapper for this could be too complicated for you.

If you don't want to use tools like [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip), because they need a setup or are to "large" for you. There are just two alternatives.

1. *Writing an own pure AutoIt ISO-9660 UDF* with [this datasheet about the ISO file format](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-119.htm)
2. Or (IMHO) the easier way:

   - Deal with it.
   - Download 7z as non-setup
   - Extract 7z.exe
   - Copy it to the directory of your script
   - Use this at the start of your script: **[`FileInstall ( "7z.exe", @TempDir & "MyProject/7z.exe" ,1)`](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileInstall.htm)***
   - Use this to extract ISO image files: `Run(@TempDir & "MyProject/7z.exe x -y -o" & $OutPutDir &" "&$IsoFile)`*

   **(You can also use **@AppDataDir** instead of **@TempDir**)*